# change drupal 7 views menu title at runtime from code

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

All,

I can't find a way to change the menu title of a drupal views page view programmatically at runtime. I've looked at the $view object, but don't see the page settings menu tab title slot.

Any clues?

Thanks

[Edit]

I found an answer:

For the curious, it turns out that hook_menu_local_tasks_alter(&$data, $router_item, $root_path) provides access to menu titles at runtime. dpm($data) will show you how.

Comment: How about instead of placing real view title you set some tag (code, dummy string) and in template file you run simple search/replace...replacing your tag with real title?